# Javascript Color Selector to change Background Color

Tags: jquery, html, css

I have been trying to re-create a Color Selector function that is found here:

http://www.chismbrothers.com/site/colorit

I think I have most of the functionality in JSFiddle but Im missing something or a few things.

```js
$('.color').hover(function(){
    $('#image').css({
        'background-color':$(this).css('background-color')
    });
})
```

```css
#image {
    background: url(http://www.chismbrothers.com/images/woodfloors.png);
    height: 341px;
    width: 515px;
}

.color {
    width: 50px;
    height: 50px;
    display: block;
    float: left;
    margin: 5px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id='image'></div>
<span class='color' style='background-color: #fe4'></span>
<span class='color' style='background-color: #e14'></span>
<span class='color' style='background-color: #410'></span>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/NinjaSk8ter/ryLDn/

since this rely's on changing the color of 2 Images, Im not even sure how to upload those on JSFiddle.

Can someone point me in the right direction?  What am I missing? How much am I missing?

Comment: For start, you have to select "no wrap" and "no library" in the left menu - here is updated version: http://jsfiddle.net/yahavbr/EvnJM/4/

Comment: i have added a fiddle to my example below

Answer (score 6, accepted):

if u look at the image that ur 1st link shows: [image]

it is made using a transparent background. when u hover over the different colors, it changed the css of the background color.

and here is a working example using jquery:  http://jsfiddle.net/maniator/H6Bg6/ (fiddle does not work as the color picker liobrary does not seem to exist anymore)

This can also be done in straight up javascript like so:

```js
const colorChosen = document.getElementById('colorChosen');
const image = document.getElementById('image');

document.querySelector('.color').addEventListener('change', ({
  currentTarget
}) => {
  image.style.backgroundColor = currentTarget.value;
  colorChosen.textContent = currentTarget.value;
});
```

```css
#image {
  background: url(https://i.stack.imgur.com/5O4iO.png);
  height: 341px;
  width: 515px;
}

.color {
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  float: left;
  margin: 5px 0px;
}
```

```html
<div id='image' style='background-color: #fdee44'></div>
<input value="#fdee44" class="color" type="color" />
<span id="colorChosen">#fdee44</span>
```

Comment: @Neal how is determined what area of that image gets the background color?  I dont see it.

Comment: .... inspect the image in something like photoshop or in chrome's inspect element and u will see that the walls are transparent, so whatever color u put behind them shines thru

Comment: @Neal yea really nice catch.  How is that you have 1/10th the javascript that I have?  For example the Tab routine?

Comment: @Paul ,  i am using jQuery Library

Comment: @Neal so I should edit this Title now, so people can search on this.  Thanks for your help I would have never figured it out.

Comment: and that is why stackoverflow allows u to accept correct answers ^_^ so people can learn from them :-)

Comment: @Neal yes I deleted that one- it was very bad.

Comment: lol u shouldnt delete, now people cant see what u tryed ^_^ :-p

Comment: @Neal  I hope to be albe to expand on this using this custom color picker as well:  http://www.eyecon.ro/colorpicker/#about

Comment: @Neal I did, i hit you up on your chat

Comment: @Paul here is an example with the color picker: http://jsfiddle.net/maniator/GXuqb/ :-) your welcome ^_^

Comment: @Paul im on my chat thing now if u need help